# jquery отправка данных из диалогового окна на основную страницу

Tags: jquery, popup

Прошу подсказать, как реализовать отправку данных из диалогового окна на страницу с которой было открыто это диалоговое окно. Естественно без обновления страницы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте повесить обработчик события при отправке информации(клике, потере фокуса с элемента). При отработке данного события добавьте нужную информацию в необходимое место вашего документа. Выглядеть это может примерно таким образом:

```js
$('.processed_item').on('click', function(){
  $('insert_element').val($('.elem_with_text').val());
  $('.this_popUp').remove();
});
```